# Is there a special name for thermodynamic process during which no work is performed?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, work

Let $W$ denote the work done on a system during a thermodynamic process.  Is there a commonly-accepted, dedicated term for a process during which $W=0$?

Comment: @garyp I'm looking for a word covering all forms of energy transfer other than heat.

Comment: What is your definition of $W$ in the case of a nonideal gas, say?

Answer (score 1):

Not in general, no. In the special case of no *volumetric* work being done, we call the process **isochoric**. Volumetric work occurs when there is a change in the volume of the system, whether due to an external agent or due to the system itself. There are plenty of ways, however, that work could be done on a system without impacting its volume -- examples include rotating a rigid paddle in the system, passing a small electric current through it, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's called isochoric process. For thermodynamical systems, work done is always associated with change in volume. When change in volume is 0, I.e. process is isochoric, no work is done

Comment: I don't think this is right -- work is not always associated with a change in volume.  Work of this sort is called mechanical work, but their are other kinds.  Consider, for example, a classical ideal gas for which during a quasistatic process $dU = \delta Q - PdV + \mu dN$.  The $\mu dN$ term is work associated with a change in particle number, often called chemical work.

Comment: @user94781 This is incorrect: what you are referring to is volume-based work, which is only one type of work that can be performed. There are several ways to exert work on a thermodynamic system without changing its volume. For instance, rotating a rigid paddle, passing an electric current, etc. all do work without necessarily expanding or contracting the system.